# How does Delphi XE4 calculate variant type values

Tags: delphi, variant

I have written a parser that takes an array of variant, and according to type, creates a string.
I use this string as the basis of an SQL request.

Reading the documentation : https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Variants.VarType
I can see that there are 21 CONSTANT values that represent the various types.

here is a snippet to extract the type index :`typ := VarType(bob);` Where typ is an integer and bob is a variant.

I would expect from the documentation that a varString would have a "typ" of 19.  However it returns 258.

Looking here : https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.TVarData
I can see this:  `#define varString (WordWord_Type)(256)`

So the documentation indicates that varString can be 19 OR 256, so why do I get 258?

Comment: Decimal 258 is hexadecimal 102, so it's [`varUString: Integer = $102;`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System#Constants) - use the constants.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. How do you build the SQL string? Are you using SQL parameters?

Comment: @DelphiCoder - No, it's someone else's code and they have a module that handles SQL calls.  This company only recently moved from Midas to ADO  This module does not have a parameterised query generator.   The parser is my attempt to add parameterisation.     I am sorry, I don't know what an "XY" problem is, I'll look it up.

Comment: @AmigoJack  I don't understand your answer, the constants indicate either 19 or 256  neither being 258, which is the actual result.

Comment: @ammigoJack  Ahhhh, you meant : https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System#Constants

Comment: I meant what I linked to. Blue and underlined = link - welcome to the internet.

Comment: It's still unclear why you have to work with variants.

Comment: Immaterial. My question was why does the official documentation for the VarType have a value in that is incorrect for the purpose?  I now understand that I have to go to the cellar, behind the basilisk, and read an entirely different set of instructions that are not indicated on the VarType info page.  It is unclear why you replied.

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect from the documentation that a varString would have a "typ" of 19.

Why would you expect that? Per the documentation:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System#Constants

`varLongWord`/`varUInt32` (ie, 32bit unsigned integer) has a numeric value of **decimal 19**, hex $13.

On the other hand, `varString` (ie `AnsiString`) has a numeric value of **decimal 256**, hex $100. And `varUString` (ie `UnicodeString`) had a numeric value of **decimal 258**, hex $102.

Delphi's native `String` type has been `UnicodeString` since Delphi 2009, hence why you are receiving `varUString` values.

BTW, the RTL has a [`VarToStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarToStr) function that converts a `Variant` to a `String`, supporting all of the various types that a `Variant` can hold.  You don't need to do the conversion manually.